# Extract text from string and write to another string

Tags: java

I have string like this: "Welcome  Vitalii Mckay   "
I need to cut from this string my name and surname, it should left in new string: "Mckay, Vitalii".

But it should be good not just for my name, it should works for other names with different length, for example:

- "Welcome  John Smith   " -> "Smith, John"

  or
- "Welcome  Andrea J.   " -> "J., Andrea".

Comment: Is "Welcome" is static word for each?

Comment: yes, it's. I've edited a little

Comment: what is logic behind `"Welcome Andrea J. " -> "J., John".` ?

Comment: String st = "Welcome John Smith"; st.substring(8);

Comment: my mistake, sry, edited "Welcome Andrea J. " -> "J., Andrea".

Comment: Have you tried do it yourself?, has tried anything or are you asking for your homework to get done by others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on @Vishal's answer and OP's comment on @Max's answer, I believe this will work:

```
String name = " Welcome Vitalii Mckay "; // with spaces in the beginning and in the end
String[] parts = name.trim().split(" "); // you don't really need the \\
name = parts[2] + ", " + parts[1];
```

Just make sure you **trim** your `String` input.

Answer (score 4):

```
String name = "Welcome Vitalii Mckay";
String[] parts = name.split("\\ ");
name = parts[2] + ", " + parts[1];
```

Comment: how to make for name like: " Wellcome Vitalii Mckay "? I have spaces before welcome and after surname

Comment: Thanks for your answer this answer is helpful for me.

Answer (score 2):

Could you just use a delimiter?

i.e. use a delimiter to separate the three strings, and only print out the two needed values (Surname [2]/Firstname [1])

```
  String s = "Welcome Vitalii Mckay";

   String[] split = s.split("\\s+"); 

    System.out.println(split[2] + ", " + split[1]);
```

Comment: Thank you, it works, but not correct, because of I have string with spaces in the end, like: String s = "Welcome Vitalii Mckay  ", and after I have result like this: 'Vitalii, Wellcome'

Comment: how to make for name like: "  Wellcome Vitalii Mckay  "?

Comment: Could you give me an example of what the whole string is?

Comment: Ensure you're using the correct array values, in the above code:
[0] = "Welcome"
[1] = "Vitali"
[2] = "Mckay"

Answer (score 1):

```
// "Welcome" 
// followed by the not of space one or more times
// then a space
// followed by anything one or more times
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("Welcome ([^ ]+) (.+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("Welcome Vitalii Mckay");
if (!matcher.matches()) throw new Exception();
String firstName = matcher.group(1); // groups are captured between ()
String lastName = matcher.group(2); // groups are captured between ()
```